# How to escape this obfuscated string?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am searching a text file using the `Select-String` method and the `-pattern` tag. What I *want* to search the file for are matches of: `ball":[]`

Here is what I have tried:

``` Select-String $textFile -pattern 'ball:"``[``]' ```

`Select-String $textFile -pattern "ball:"bTick[bTick]"`  (bTick = back tick `)

Pretty much every combination of back ticks and quotations I can think of. I know back ticks are the way to escape square brackets in Powershell but I can't seem to find an example online that includes two empty square brackets, a colon, *and* a double quotation. What is the proper way to escape this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select-String $textFile -pattern "ball`":\[]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape it using `[regex]::escape('text')` or use simply  add `-SimpleMatch` to use your pattern unescaped. Like this:

```
Select-String -Path $textFile -Pattern 'ball":[]' -SimpleMatch

Select-String -Path $textFile -Pattern ([regex]::escape('ball":[]'))
```